# can't connect to BigBlueButton from external address

Tags: networking, server, nginx

I installed a bigbluebutton server ver 0.81.
When i set ip using

```
sudo bbb-conf --setip 192.168.0.190
```

It's the local ip address and it work fine.

but when i switch to my external static IP:

```
sudo bbb-conf --setip 118.70.177.191
```

then i connect to `http://118.70.177.191/` the browser can't connect to it. (Connect timeout)

But the link `http://118.70.177.191/bigbluebutton/api` response:

```
<response>
   <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
   <version>0.81</version>
</response>
```

I can't use the API because of connect timeout or run the Demo page.
Plz help me resolve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/hosts:

192.168.0.190 118.70.177.191

Save it and run sudo bbb-conf --setip 118.70.177.191

Answer (score 0):

We would recommend you provide your server with a fully qualified domain name with a SSL certificate.  You can't put two IP addresses in the HOSTS file.

If your trying to use BigBlueButton behind a firewall, the docs are pretty detailed.  See

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html#configure-the-firewall-if-required

--

Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer